# How to scroll a TextBox down automatically in dm-script

Tags: textbox, scrollbar, dm-script

How do I scroll down a dialog `TextBox` automatically when updating the text?

---

Consider the following example dialog (code below).

[image]

This contains a `TextBox`. As soon as the text changes, the textbox will update. The text changes every 0.5 seconds which is invoked by another thread. (The text is the current date in your language.) As one can seen in the above image, the scroll bar is at the very top. But this hampers the user from getting the newest status at the first glance. The user has to scroll down manually and keep the mouse clicked because otherwise the textbox will jump to the start again.

How can I change this behaviour? I want the user to see the lastly added text always. So in other words: How do I set the scroll bar position?

---

Note: I thought about inserting the new text in the front. But this is unintuitive. The dialog shows the status of a measurement. Each step is done with several status updates which are done separately. So either I create "blocks" for each step that get inserted at the top. But then cannot show the status updates when the actually happen (which I strongly want to avoid) because I have to create the block first. Or I can add every line to the top which looks extremely confusing (I tried that already) because the order is completely weird.

---

```c
string text = "";
number running = 1;
number update_task;

class UpdateThread : Thread{
    void RunThread(object self){
        while(running){
            text += "It is now " + FormatTimeString(GetCurrentTime(), 34) + "\n";
            sleep(0.5);
        }
    }
}

class ExampleDialog : UIFrame{
    void update(object self){
        TagGroup field = self.lookupElement("textbox");
        if(field.TagGroupIsValid()){
            self.SetTextElementData("textbox", text);
            
            field.DLGInvalid(1);
            self.validateView();
        }
    }
    
    object init(object self){
        TagGroup dlg, dlg_items, field;
        
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Example", dlg_items);
        
        field = DLGCreateTextBox(100, 10, 10000);
        field.DLGIdentifier("textbox");
        dlg.DLGAddElement(field);
        
        update_task = AddMainThreadPeriodicTask(self, "update", 0.1);
        
        self.super.init(dlg);
        return self;
    }
}

alloc(UpdateThread).StartThread();
alloc(ExampleDialog).init().pose();
running = 0;
RemoveMainThreadTask(update_task);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the functionality you are after does currently exist in GMS (3.4.2), but I can certainly see why it would be useful to have.

You might want to consider adding it as a feature request via the software-issue-reporting form at Gatan.

Comment: That's bad news. I will send the request as soon as the [bug report site](http://swbugs.gatan.com/loginsolosubmit.htm) works again. Currently it is not answering

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextBox.appendText()` method.

Comment: I get an error `No match for appendText()`. Neither `self.appendText("id", text);` nor `field.appendText(text)` work. And I don't even get suggestions for this method. Are you sure this is a `dm-script` method? Or is it maybe added with the new version?